# What Tailwind utilities would I use to have no spacing between the text in two spans?

Tags: tailwind-css

Given this:

```
    <div>
        <span class="font-extrabold">AAA</span>
        <span class="font-medium">bbb</span>
    </div>
```

How do I have the text appear as **AAA**bbb with no extra space between **AAA** and bbb?

Comment: Inline parent elements behave weird with whitespace in source code. You'll need to mangle your source code to remove the new lines and tabs, add negative margins, or use a different display method for your parent, like `flex`.

This might be helpful for a solution: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: @LyndenNoye That link led to the solution: putting `class="flex"` in the div element. If you put the link in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline elements interact unexpectedly with whitespace present in your source code. This might be helpful for a solution: [css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Essentially:

- Minimise your HTML to remove the whitespace
- Splitting the opening/closing tags to cover the new line and indentation
- Using and the start/end of each line to create the new lines and indentation
- Negative margins
- A few other hacks...
- Changing the display of the parent to `flex`

Comment: Changing the display of the parent to `flex` worked for me